# Firebase Cloud Functions Database Trigger 'onCreate is not a function'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I want to use **onCreate** method instead of **onWrite** for the sake of efficiency but I face that error:

> *functions.database.ref(...).onCreate is not a function*.

However, there seems to be a function as mentioned in the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onCreate

My code starts as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.manager = functions.database.ref('some_ref')
    .onCreate(event =>{
```

I am looking forward to your helps.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: a full code snippet will be more efficient to understand the full picture. without it, i would guess that you forgot to require the functions package?

Comment: `onCreate()` is a new feature that was released in the last few days.  I'm guessing something in your build config needs to be updated, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Yeah, I have just seen that it was released 2 days ago so i better do some update

Comment: Run `npm upgrade` from your functions folder to upgrade your node modules.  You need firebase-functions with at least version 0.5.9.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:**  In a comment on the question, Firebaser Doug Stevenson indicates that running  `npm upgrade` in the project's functions folder is the simpler way to update to the latest version.

---

I don't find any documentation for how to update to the latest version of `firebase-functions`.  Following the [general guidelines described here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/dependencies#installing_nodejs_modules_with_npm), go to your project's functions directory and enter this command:

```
npm install --save firebase-functions
```

You can then look in the `package.json` file to see the versions installed.  The [new version](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases) of `firebase-functions` that contains the new triggers is 0.5.9